# wedge/saddle rail mounted bags interchange

Tags: mountain-bike, product-rec, accessories, bags

A variety of manufacturers make snap in wedge bag mounts. The mount attaches to the saddle rails and the bag snaps into the mount.  Does  know which brands if any interchange?

Comment: I would be surprised if any distinct brands interchange.  You may, of course, find the same line of bags sold under different brand names, especially with the "no-name" brands.

Comment: You can also get wedge bags that use straps and/or velcro instead of fixed mounts, if you just want to move a saddlebag between bikes and aren't already dependent on a specific fixed mount.

Comment: The issue is that the bags that are secure enough for mountain biking use multiple straps and can be a pain to install and remove. The easy install type have a tendency to fall off.

Comment: I guess this is an MTB thing then (and tagged it as such). I have one of [these](http://www.topeak.com/products/Wedge-Packs-Strap), and I can't imagine loading enough weight in there that it could generate enough force to break the webbing or the buckles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a quick connect system that works with different manufacturers, but have found a bag that I can easily swap between bikes without needing to buy two bags.

I use a Topeak Aero Wedge Medium saddle bag and have found on their support website ([store.todson.com](http://store.todson.com)) that you can buy extra "fixers" to put on each of your bicycles. The medium Aero Wedge saddle bag carries a couple tubes and my compact pump. It has the quick connect and a single velcro strap which goes around the seat post. Very secure.

I have not had any problems with the Wedge saddle bag when mountain biking (I don't go off many jumps but lots of cross country, single track and rough terrain).

After about 4 years, I did have the thin plastic slot thingy (official term I think) on the bag become brittle and crack. I found the replacement on the store.todson.com website and did not need to purchase a new bag, as such I still recommend the Topeak Wedge bags.

Answer (score 0):

I can now say that at least as far as Avenir and Zefal are concerned they do not interchange. I did find that Avenir sells a kit to convert any wedge bag to quick release. It involves making a small hole in the bag,inserting a small plate inside and screwing it to the clip on the outside.